# Encoding characters in Workflow Max job numbers

Tags: xero-api

I'm working with a set of **Workflox Max** jobs which contain the characters `.` and `/` in their job number (also referred to as the job id in parts of the [API docs](https://www.workflowmax.com/api/v3/job-methods). Examples of these job numbers would be:

```
J1234.5
J1234/5
```

I would like to call the `GET get/[job number]` jobs method which, for the first example, would be:

```
https://api.xero.com/workflowmax/3.0/job.api/get/J1234.5
```

However, this URL is failing with

```
Bad response 404
```

I've tried `%2E` as a substitution for `.` and this is also not resolving, and similarly for `%2F` for `/`.

Is there any way of encoding `.` or `/` so that I can use the jobs methods with such job numbers?

I have completed authentification, and am receiving data for other job numbers without these characters.  I hope the use of the Xero API tag is ok, given there is no WFM tag

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, the Xero Central helpdesk have told me that these characters are not currently supported in job numbers.